# AJAX request hits server from every page and I can't find the source of that original AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Somewhere in my thousands of lines of javascript, an ajax call is being made.  I cannot for the life of me figure out where it is coming from.  It seems to happen right after a page loads.

I can see in firebug that the ajax call is being made.  The ajax call always requests the current page. So, for example, once `users#new` loads, it asks for `users#new.js` and also does the same with every other controller and action.

Is there a way I can determine where in the code it is being called from?

Comment: Isolate it based on what controller action is being called

Comment: it happens on every page / action

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  You said that you can see an ajax call being made in Firebug, right?  So, check what path is being requested in that ajax call and that will isolate it to a certain controller/action.  For instance, if the AJAX call hits the `/users/new` path in your server logs then it's likely related to the `users#new` action.  That should allow you to isolate which JS code could make that call.

Comment: I wasn't clear :)  The ajax call always requests the current page.  So once users#new loads, it asks for users#new.js  same with every other controller and action.

Comment: Well that's no good :)  Might want to look through your code for areas where ajax calls are not wrapped in a javascript click (or other event) handler.  If it's happening on DOM load, then it'd have to be in something that is not dependent upon a certain event (click, change, etc.) occurring.

Comment: @recursive_acronym what are you using to make the AJAX calls - `XMLHttpRequest` or some wrapper/library?

Comment: Programmer Error.  At some point I re-wrote my ajax setup and I wrote $.ajax({...}) instead of $.ajaxSetup({...})  so what I thought was the setup was actually making an ajax call.  Dumb dumb dumb   thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in time I re-wrote my ajax setup function.

$.ajax != $.ajaxSetup, obviously :)

Answer (score 1):

Although you've already found a solution, you could still remedy the situation using the debugger. Let's say you were using jQuery and its AJAX helpers, simply set a breakpoint in the [first line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L386) of the `$.ajax` method.

When a call is made to `$.ajax`, the runtime will halt at the breakpoint and you can look at the call stack to figure out exactly where the call came from.

If you were using the `XMLHttpRequest` constructor directly instead of via jQuery or some other wrapper, then replace the original `XMLHttpRequest` constructor function with a dummy implementation for the purpose of tracing its caller.

```
function XMLHttpRequest() {
    this.open = function() {}; // ignore
    this.send = function() {
        debugger;
    };
}
```

Place a breakpoint or invoke the debugger programmatically in the send method of this overridden implementation, and whenever somebody tries to instantiate a new `XMLHttpRequest` object and call the `send` method, you can intercept the call and look at the call trace to figure out who made the call.

There are plenty of good debugging options like Firebug for Firefox, or the built-in Developer Tools in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript console, you could override `XMLHttpRequest.send()` with your own implementation and set a break point there so you can examine the stack trace in the debugger when it is called.

```
var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
    send.apply(this, arguments); // set break point here
};
```